# Does the at symbol (@) before a definition name mean something?

Tags: macros

I'm using a resume template and see this pattern a lot in the template. What is the purpose of this redirection to `@name`, does the `@` symbol mean anything special, and how do I use it to modify the formatting of my name?

```
% use this to define your name
%
\def\name#1{\def\@name{#1}}

\def\@name{}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "top-level" command `\name` is used to assign a value to the internal variable `\@name` which is then used by `\maketitle`. (I'm borrowing programming slang here: for `TeX` they're both control sequences.) Macros containing `@` are internal macros, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/82917.

Comment: `@` in a macro name is not allowed outside of packages or classes unless within `\makeatletter...\makeatother`. It is used in order to provide macros that should not be applied directly by normal LaTeX users other than developers because those macros are 'crucial' and need special care, not being called accidentally. Think of `@` as a 'separator' of user - macros and internal macros. Almost any LaTeX kernel macro starts with `\@...`